# How to show jquery dialog with ok button?

Tags: jquery

Here's my code:

```
$("#success").dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: 'Payment success',
    width: 400,
});
```

How can I show an `OK` button in this dialog?

Comment: I think you should add another key `buttons : {"ok" : function(){}}` along with the other properties.

Comment: Everything you need is in the API docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan GJ , but why not posting this as answer ? ^^

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use [Buttons option](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons) and see the [Modal Message](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message).

```
$("#success").dialog({
  modal:true,
  title:'Payment success',
  width:400,
  buttons: {
    Ok: function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#success").dialog({modal:true,title:'Payment success',width:400,buttons{"Ok":execute,"Cancel": cancel}});

var execute = function()
{
    alert('This is Ok button');
}

var cancel = function()
{
    alert('This is Cancel button');
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#success").dialog({
modal:true,
title:'Payment success',
width:400,
buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
});
```

This should add a button with the text 'Ok', when you click the button the dialog will close :)

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/